# Parallax is not scrolling

Tags: parallax.js

I'm using the parallax.jx. It shows the image just right, but the image doesn't scroll at a lower speed, it is fixed on the page. Does anyone know why it does this and how I can fix it?

**HTML**:

```
`<head>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon64.png"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test js.css">`<br/>
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
 </script>`<br/>
`<script src="parallax.js"></script>
</head>`

`<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-speed="0.5" data-image-src="Groepsfoto.jpeg">
</div>`
```

---

**CSS**

```
 `.parallax-window <br/> {
        height: 34.13vw; <br/>
        background: transparent; <br/>
    }`
```